# How to keep Ext.Panel scrollbar position between tabs switching

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tabpanel and inside one of its tabs I have a simple `Ext.Panel` component with `scrollable` property set to true, just like this:

```
scrollable: true
```

The problem is, when I go to another tab and then go back, the scroller moves to a zero position. I do not like this and my users do no like this too. I need to keep scroller where it was left, but I do not know how. I guess, I need something like [preserveScrollOnRefresh](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.view.AbstractView.html#cfg-preserveScrollOnRefresh), but it is a private method and I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Are you reloading the content in the tab after switching back to it?

Comment: I can't reproduce that: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/24qb

Answer (score 1):

The key point is what happens to the panel when it gets out of the view and when it is displayed again.

As @Tyr says, if you rerender the panel when activating it, you will not be able to keep the scroll position. This is also true if you reload the store in a grid, or if you configured the panel to be destroyed when it gets hidden.

I hope this helps you to find the problem. Otherwise you have to show more code or create a fiddle.